# Regex Conditional Statement with Lookbehind

Tags: regex

So I am trying to have a regular expression that uses a lookbehind to find the previous character and have conditions on the current character.  Basically if the previous character is a 1 then the current character can only be 5-9 or if the previous character is 9, the current character can only be 0-4, otherwise it can be any digit. Here is the regex I am trying but it is not working.

`[1-9]((?(?<=1)[5-9]|[0-9])|(?(?<=9)[0-4]|[0-9]))$`

Comment: Does the whole string consist of digits?

Comment: No, this is part of a larger regular expression that uses letters and special characters to create a username.

Comment: Don't know, but probably something like this? https://regex101.com/r/vN8vR9/1 Anyway, can't you include the logic in the routine to create username instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you are going to embed it in a larger regex:

```
(?:[02-8]|1(?![^5-9])|9(?![^0-4]))+
```

The idea is to check as you consume the characters:

- For 0 and 2-8, there is no restriction, so just consume them `[02-8]`
- For 1, we **don't** want to consume it if the character ahead (if any) is **not** 5-9, and `(?![^5-9])` do just that.
- Same for 9, `(?![^0-4])` disallows 9 to be consumed if it is followed by some character other than 0-4.